# How to create a 2D array based on user variables in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create a 2D array that stores users input but am having difficult doing so. I'm asking users how many days of shipping they need, and then after the users specify X amount of days, I'm asking them how many items do they need shipped on a particular day.[Y]

For example:
Prompt user to enter how many days off shipping they need . User enters X 
Okay, on Day 1 how many items do you need shipped. User enters val1
Okay on Day 2 ..... User enters val2
etc.. up to Day X

I want to create a 2D array to solve this but not sure how to initialize and then populate it.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: arrays must have a constant value by the compilation time......

Comment: why 2d array, why not 1D array ?

Comment: I don't see what use a 2D array would be to this problem?

Comment: Use pointers and allocate size dynamically.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar or he can use a vector which is safer.

Comment: define a struct `DailyShipment` that contains a `std::vector` of items to be shipped and then create a `std::vector` containing instances of that struct

Comment: @Eddge Yes, that too.

Comment: Do you know how to do something simpler? Like construct a 1D array of a size specified by the user? Or hard-code a 2D array?

Comment: `std::vector< std::vector< int > >` or as @tobi303 mentioned a vector of custom structs, where each has internal vector representing days. You could do then simple 2-nested for loops where the outer for loops over the users and inner for loops over single days.

Answer (score 0):

For one user, you could use a 1D "array" but need to manage thememory yourself.
Alternatively you could use a `std::vector` to store the values.
That you have a total number of days and a specific value for each of these days isn't the same as a 2D "array" of data.

```
int main()
{
    int input;
    cout << "how many?" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    int * one_way = new int[input];
    std::vector<int> or_another_way;
    for (int i = 0; i < input; ++i)
    {
        int number;
        cout << "how many on day " << i+1 << "?" << endl;
        cin >> number;
        one_way[i] = number;
        or_another_way.push_back(number);
    }
    delete[] one_way;
}
```

---

And as if to prove my point, as the comments note, I originaly just had

```
delete one_way;
```

but you need to remember the `delete[]` version goes with `new[]`.

Error prone...

Use the `std::vector`.

Comment: And just from this example you prove the point that `one_way` should not be used.

Comment: you need to match each `new` with `delete` and each `new[]` with `delete[]` or even better match no `new` with no `delete`, ie use a `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to play with 2D arrays it's an option to build one dinamically yourself, let's say you'll be storing `int` inside:

```
int** array2d;
int x,y;
//Fill x and y with user input here
array2d = new int*[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    array2d[i] = new int[y];

array2d[X][Y]; //use like this

//don't forget to clean after yourself ;)
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    delete[] array2d[i];
delete[] array2d;
```

I'm strongly advising to wrap this construct with a `class` so you'll be shure, that everything is nice and clean. For example:

```
class Array2D
{
private:
    int** array2d;
    int xSize, ySize;
    Array2D()
    {
        xSize = ySize = 0;
        array2d = nullptr;
    }
public:
    Array2D(int x, int y)
    {
        array2d = nullptr;
        xSize = x;
        ySize = y;
        array2d = new int*[xSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < xSize; i++)
            if (ySize > 0)
                array2d[i] = new int[ySize];
            else
                array2d[i] = nullptr;
    }

    ~Array2D()
    {
        if (xSize != 0 && ySize != 0)//checking for nullptr is better
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < xSize; i++)
                delete[] array2d[i];
            delete[] array2d;
        }
        else if (xSize != 0 && ySize == 0)//here nullptr check is also advised
        {
            delete[] array2d;
        }
    }

    int getXY(int x, int y)
    {
        return array2d[x][y];
    }

    void setXY(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        //of coure check constraints also ;)
        array2d[x][y] = z;
    }
};
```